# how to add remove url from urls.py in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Agency.agency has a field named URL,for example I add 2 Agencies that the first one give the value of A to URL and the second one give the value of B to URL field.now I wanna override save_model method in index in views.py to add Agencie's URL to urls.py when adding an Agency,like this:

```
(r'^airAgency/A/$','airAgency.views.index'),
(r'^airAgency/B/$','airAgency.views.index'),
```

so,when enter http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/A the index view detect which Agency I wanna access and pass its data to the page.now I have 2 question:

1. how can I add/remove url to urls.py when overriding save method in views.py
2. when user enter a URL in browser how can I parse it and find out which Agency he wanna access to send that Agency Information.
   about the first question I searched a lot but I didn't find anything.for second question I googled and I found out how to parse the requested URL,but U think doing string search in Agency Table based on its URL field is a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said and/or pointed to, don't hardcode specific Agencies into your urls.py
Keep it generic and DRY by allowing variables in your urls

```
# urls
(r'^airAgency/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', 'airAgency.views.index'),
   # this passes the value there as 'name' to the view for index

#views
def index(request, name):   # it needs to know name will be passed to it
    some_query = Agency.objects.filter( agency_name = name )
    #should also add catching for unknown objects to go to 404s
    ...
    return some_sort_of_http_response
```

more examples are in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#example)